# ValidationPipe doesn't strip given object in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm using Nestjs and Mongoose orm the problem is ValidationPipe doesn't delete invalid props from request and send given(raw) request to my service.

This is **main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
      cors: { origin: '*' },
    });

   app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(
     {
        transform: true,
        whitelist: true,
     }
   ))

   await app.listen(3002);
}
bootstrap();
```

and this is **update-category.dto**

```
export class UpdateCategoryDto {

 @IsDefined()
 id:string

 @IsDefined()
 title: string;

 @IsDefined()
 url: string;

}
```

And finally this is **category.service**

```
async updateCategories(categories: [UpdateCategoryDto]){
   for (let i = 0; i < categories.length ; i++) {
      console.log("given categories",categories);
      await this.categoryModel.updateOne([{ _id: categories[i].id }],categories[i]);
   
   }
}
```

Here is my simple controller

```
@Controller('categories')
export class CategoryController {

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}



  @Put()
  editCategories( @Body() updateCategories: [UpdateCategoryDto]) {
    return this.categoryService.updateCategories(updateCategories);
  }

}
```

when "given categories" logs items, they have _id which frontend sent to api while I didn't whitelisted that props in my dto. why I'm receaving that prop?? I also tried `forbidNonWhitelisted' and interestingly request didn't fail :)) seems useGlobalPipes doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you show the controller as well?

Comment: Generics (which arrays are) cannot properly be reflected by Typescript. This is why Nest has the `ParseArrayPipe` for when you explicitly need to validate an array as the body

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I changed my controller to this `editCategories( @Body(new ParseArrayPipe()) updateCategories: [UpdateProductCategoryDto])` nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`ParseArrayPipe`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#parsing-and-validating-arrays).

Update your `controller.ts`:

```js
@Put()
editCategories(@Body(new ParseArrayPipe({ items: UpdateCategoryDto, whitelist: true })) updateCategories: UpdateCategoryDto[]) {
  return this.categoryService.updateCategories(updateCategories);
}
```

Ensure to have `items` and `whitelist` set.